# Using System.Windows.Forms reference in MVC application

Tags: .net, winforms, asp.net-mvc-4

I have been migrating our existing Desktop based(Winform) project into MVC.
There are few legacy classes which are derived from UserControl of windows forms class.

I want use the collection of those class instances into my MVC view, by iterating the collection I'm building html controls using properties of our legacy class.

For this I have added "@using System.Windows.Forms" reference in view but it is showing below two exceptions 
Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Forms' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

And

Error   CS0012  The type 'UserControl' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

Even though I have added references of "System.Windows.Forms.dll" & "PresentationFramework.dll".

Note:My MVC project is targeting .net 4.5.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Having windows forms reference in an MVC project sounds odd. Try to remove the windows forms base class from the legacy classes that you want to use in your MVC project.

Comment: @Martin I am not able to do that, because of the legacy code implications, Is there any way rather than this?

Comment: @user2067120 Forget about reusing those User Controls. Create models and controllers and business logic classes and put every thing in the correct place.